# How to use values from another column in the proceeding row in R while iterating?

Tags: r, finance

I am trying to iterate over several years where I have an initial value and some costs that vary through time depending on the previous years final value. I am trying to iterate this calculation of the costs and final values.

That is so say that first the costs are calculated depending on the initial value, these costs are then subtracted and to determine the final value of this year which becomes next years initial value and the costs for that period are calculated and then subtracted again over n iterations.

So, how do I get last years final value (from the row above) as this years initial value?

`

```
year <- 1


cost_function <- function(year) {
  period_costs <- (year * 1000 + year ^ 3)
  return(period_costs)
}

df <- tibble(year = 1:10, 
             initial_value = c(50000, "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"),
             cost = cost_function(year)
            ) 
view(df)
```

`

In this example the costs in year 1 are 1001, so the final value of year 1 should be 48999 which becomes the initial value of year two. How would I code this in R?

I have tried with mutates and that hasn't worked. I have thought about the order of operations for the map function for this, but to use them I would still need to call the final values from the year before which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(first(initial_value)) - cumsum(cost))
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    year initial_value  cost value
   <int> <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 50000          1001 48999
 2     2 -              2008 46991
 3     3 -              3027 43964
 4     4 -              4064 39900
 5     5 -              5125 34775
 6     6 -              6216 28559
 7     7 -              7343 21216
 8     8 -              8512 12704
 9     9 -              9729  2975
10    10 -             11000 -8025
```

**Note**: Your `cost_function` can be simplyfied to

```r
cost_function <- function(year) {
  year * 1000 + year ^ 3
}
```